# how to map keyboard

Tags: c#, .net

I am mapping the keyboard but it is not working on some characters or keys like f, g, [, ], ;, '', \, / so what would be the possible solution so that I code map the whole keyboard. This is the code which I try and its working on some keys but did not work on some keys

```
private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals(";"))
   {
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      richTextBox.AppendText("Ū");
   }
   else if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals("/"))
   {
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      richTextBox.AppendText("X̄");
   }
   else if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals("g"))
   {
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      richTextBox.AppendText("Ʒ");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this approach, using the proper Keys enumeration, and e.SuppressKeyPress.

```
private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
            // Handle special keys (Alt)
            if (e.Alt)
            {
                switch (e.KeyCode)
                {
                    case Keys.K:
                        richTextBox.AppendText("Alt+K pressed");
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Don't need to handle this
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Ctrl + key
            else if (e.Control)
            {


            }
            else
            { 
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.OemSemicolon:
                richTextBox.AppendText("Ū");
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;
            case Keys.OemBackslash:
                richTextBox.AppendText("X̄");
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;
            case Keys.G:
                richTextBox.AppendText("Ʒ");
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;
            default:
                // Nothing special here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, but with the addition of this line of code. e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

Comment: @SayyarHassan  Thank you, can you mark it answered? I will add your edit to my answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me that what if I want to perform a single action from 2 or 3 keys   press at a time because the characters are more than the keyboard keys.

Comment: @SayyarHassan do you mean such as Ctrl+K or Alt+Enter?

Comment: Thank you so much Jon it works. Thanks for your time.